# Removed users from Exchange Management Console (2007) , but they still show up Get-MailboxStatistics

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Title says it all.  I removed a number of users who are no longer here, they don't show up in AD, or EMC, but when I run Get-MailboxStatistics, they are still there.  It's annoying because some of their mailboxes are 10+GB.

Additionally, I know that some users have gone in and deleted 5-10GB of data from their Outlook folders, but Get-MailboxStatistics doesn't reflect this. Any idea why? How to sync them up?

Answer (score 0):

Are they disconnected users that haven't been deleted until the 30 days is up?

[Powershell Disconnected Mailboxes Exchange 2007](http://www.sysadmin-network.com/profiles/blogs/exchange-2007-powershell-1)

Comment: The ones that have deleted large chunks of their mail are active users.  They went into large mail and clearly deleted GB's of data.  The others, I removed from Exchange and AD, but they still show up.  It hasn't been 30 days yet though, so maybe that is part of it?